# Computer program to tell you

Tags: logic

Are there any computer programs, where if you input the premises and the conclusion, it tells you whether the conclusion is true or false?

Comment: You need to say something about the theories (or logics) you are interested in. A theory for which such a program exists is called *decidable*. Some theories are decidable and some aren't.

Comment: Ok, well for a decidable theory, do you have a link to such a program?

Comment: You might look into SAT solvers and SMT solvers.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem and 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories

Comment: The question seems to me almost as expecting this sort of program to be written in some C# or Java. But in fact we can easily manufacture statements whose proofs or refutations will be exceedingly long, that no proton in the universe will see the result of the program.

Answer (score 3):

See the Wikipedia article on [automated theorem proving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving) for lots of information and links. Decidable theories are actually quite rare. So a lot of research is into semi-decision procedures (that are guaranteed to find a proof for a provable theorem given enough time and space, but may search indefinitely if the conjecture isn't provable) and  also into heuristic procedures (that give good results on a useful class of problems, but with no guarantees either way). As alluded to in Robert Israel's comment, there are also procedures that guarantee to prove that a formula is satisfiable (SAT for propositional formulas, SMT for first order formulas): you can use these as "semi-refutation" procedures: if you want to prove something is false, you ask a satisfiability solver to find a counter-example to it.