# Decidability of certain first-order statements

Tags: logic, computability, proof-theory

Is it possible to construct an algorithm that can formally prove any statement in some countable first-order theory except for exactly those which aren't provable in the theory? Why or why not?

Edit: so, apparently, the answer is affirmative. Has such an algorithm already been constructed?

Edit 2: I meant countable theories.

Comment: You can't construct an algorithm that will prove statements that the theory _disproves_.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes.

Comment: Technically, we need the theory in question to be *recursively axiomatizable.*

Comment: I've changed "any statement" to "any true statement".

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm can enumerate all consequences of the axioms, and so eventually list all the provable statements and all the disprovable statements.

An algorithm can take any non-independent statement and (if it really is not independent) determine if the statement, or its negation, has a proof.

An algorithm cannot tell, given an arbitrary statement, whether it is provable, or disprovable, or independent.

Comment: OK, thanks. Has such an algorithm already been constructed?

Comment: The original question has some problems with terminology. Please don't proliferate the non-standard use of terminology.

Comment: Your claims are dependent on the theory in question (where I am using the word dependent in a standard way $\ddot{\smile}$). There **are** decidable theories, e.g., the theory of an unbounded dense linear order, or the theory of real closed fields. Your final paragraph is not true of these theories.

Comment: @gndz: if you are interested in actual implementations, then you may find some useful information in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400618/computer-program-to-tell-you/1400773#1400773

Comment: I was talking about the use of the word "independent". The OP has now fixed this in the question.

Comment: The question talked about statements "independent of the axioms".  This sounded completely clear and standard to me.  What terminology problem did you have in mind?   @RobArthan

Comment: The OP was originally using "independent of" where what was meant was "not a consequence of". That's been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your language is countable, then the answer is yes, though this answer has little to do with automated theorem proving. Let $T$ be a theory in a countable language $L$. Then the set of sentences in $L$ is countable, so the set of finite sequences of sentences in $L$ is countable. Hence the set of proofs of $T$-provable sentences is countable.

So you can list the set of all proofs of $T$-provable sentences as
$$\{ p_n : n < \omega \}$$
An algorithm which, given a $T$-provable sentence $\varphi$, returns a proof of $\varphi$, works as follows. Input a $T$-provable sentence $\varphi$. Set $n=0$. While $\varphi$ remains unproved, check if $p_n$ is a proof of $\varphi$; if so, then return $p_n$; else increment $n$.

But this is emphatically *not* what automated theorem provers do, or attempt to do.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the title was a bit misleading. I'll change it.

Comment: Two comments : (1) You need $T$ to be recursively enumerable, not just countable. (2) What traditional automated theorem provers (e.g., resolution style provers) do **is** essentially the algorithm you describe, except that they take a much more sophisticated approach to deciding which $n$ to try next.

Comment: @Rob: I agree with the remarks about the theory being RE; but in general the algorithm works. Whether or not an algorithm is only something that can be executed by a Turing machine, or just a concrete "recipe" is open for debate, though. And in the broader interpretation this is a valid answer.

Comment: By algorithm I meant Turing machines.

Comment: I am with gndz: "algorithm" should be used to mean a Turing computable process unless explicitly stated otherwise.